# Test valid URL in QGIS

Tags: qgis, url

I want check URL recorded in the field of table in QGIS, to find deadlink (7800 lines).
I can make directly in QGIS or not ? Python is not really my friend.

Comment: Python is a willing friend, and ideal for this task.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what we'll do: use the Field Calculator to add a new field based on the URL stored in another field. We'll have to use Python for this because QGIS' expressions don't have the capabilities for this.

Open the attribute table for your layer, enable the layer for editing, and open the Field Calculator (abacus icon).

Open the "Function Editor" tab and hit the green + sign and make a new file called `link` and put the following Python code in there:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

import requests

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', referenced_columns=[])
def link_check(url, feature, parent):
    try:
        r = requests.head(url,verify=False,timeout=5) # it is faster to only request the header
        return (r.status_code)
    except:
        return -1
```

It should look like this:

[image]

Save that, and go back to the Expression tab. Put `link_check(url)` in the expression (where `url` is the name of the column in your data that has URLs in it). Check "Create a new field" and give it a name like `status`. OK the dialog.

That will get you a new column with the status from trying to get that URL. 200 is a good thing, 404 means the server was okay but the page didn't exist, -1 means it failed badly. Here's a couple from my test:

[image]

There may be a QGIS plugin that does this, but I can't find it.

Doing thousands of these might take a while depending on server response, it might also, if the same server is queried thousands of times, crash the server or make it think you are trying to crash it and so block you. Please think of the servers.

Comment: See the list of possible status codes at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes